# List of tableview link to other list of tableview

Tags: xcode, tableview

Say i have a list of food table and display all food categories such as american, ltaliano and japanese. then when i click american it will show list of american food such as hamburgers. please help.

Comment: Is there any backend server you have? or you are storing your data in sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

There two ways to store data as

1) In instance variable, NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"american":@[@"hamburgers",@"french fries"], @"ltaliano" : @[@"Insalata caprese",@"Pasta e fagioli"], @"japanese": @[@"Udon noodles",@"Donburi rice bowl"]};
```

Load your table using `NSDictionary's [dict allKeys]` method and when you click on a row, get keyName from `NSDictionary's` and pass values for this key into the next `UIViewController`

2) Store your data in the `SQLite` local database with FoodCategory(have all food categories) and FoodDetails(food category and its foodName) Table. In first `UIViewController`, to display lists of food, get foodCategories from the FoodCategory table and store it into `NSArray`. Using this `NSArray` load your table. When you click on any row pass selected foodCategory to the next `UIViewController` and in this to get its foodNames, write `SELECT` query to fetch all records from FoodDetails table for selected foodCategory.

For tutorial:

[Basic UITableView tutorial1](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

[Basic UITableView tutorial2](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/)

Hope this will help you.